# How to manage display order of products in e-commerce site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am making an E-commerce site in .net(database using SQL server 2008). I want to manage display order of already added product according to admin on user side. At present Display order is desc. on both side(user and admin).

**As for example**- if admin have added 3-products(x,y,z) and now these products are showing on user side in order(z,y,x) but now admin want to change display order(y,z,x) how can he change?
thanks to all in advance.

Comment: add one column of order and give order to it. Its not the best solution but you can try this...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option would be add two columns in the table `product`

1. Display_Order
2. Admin_Display_Order

and put values as you like and in query pass the `user-type` admin or normal. And get the sorted values accordingly.